# Sorting a vector returning `()`

Tags: rust

Error is telling me that `len()` isn't implemented for type `()`.  I assume that means that `v.sort()` (below code) returned `()`?

Reproduce code is here:

```
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    println!("{}",median(vec))
}

fn median(v: Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    let sorted = v.sort();
    let med_idx = sorted.len() as i32 / 2;
    sorted[med_idx]
}
```

Comment: [`sort`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort) modifies the vector and does not return anything.
You also have a type error with `med_idx`. You can only index using `usize` but  `med_idx` is `i32`.

Comment: I just found it's an in-place function!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The sort function has the signature `pub fn sort(&mut self)` and doesn't return anything. Instead, it modifies the vector you are running it on. Since you are taking `v` as a moved parameter, we can sort that instead of cloning it. Also, since `med_idx` is indexing a vector, it should be a `usize` and not `i32`.

```
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    println!("{}", median(vec));
}

fn median(mut v: Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    v.sort();

    let med_idx = v.len() / 2;
    v[med_idx]
}
```